# In WSL, I have a Ubuntu 18.04 installation and a Ubuntu installation. Can I safely get rid of the one that's just called "Ubuntu"?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL. In Windows Terminal, when I open a new tab, I can choose between "Ubuntu" and "Ubuntu 18.04". I'm wondering what the first one is and if I can get rid of it.

In Apps & Features, both are listed as installed apps, so I assumed there were two different installations of Ubuntu. However, they are shown to have very different sizes - Ubuntu 18.04 is 13GB and Ubuntu is only 1.37GB. I figure this is either because I've been using the 18.04 one and that made it larger, or because the "Ubuntu" one is something other than a distro.

I want to remove the one called "Ubuntu" if it is a redundant Ubuntu distro, but I don't want to break my Ubuntu 18.04 installation.

Edit: Running `wsl -l -v` gave me the following information:

```
NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-18.04           Running         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
  Ubuntu                 Stopped         1
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
```

Which confirms that the "Ubuntu" instance is using the old version of WSL and can be deleted, thanks @Ramhound

Comment: What are the versions of the WSL instances in question?  You can provide that information by performing an [edit] to your question

Comment: Thanks, I think that gave me my answer. Not enough coffee yet today I guess

Comment: I actually meant WSL1 or WSL2 not the version of Ubuntu (already knew that information)

Comment: Ah, yep, "Ubuntu" is using v1, so it's definitely just an old one. Thanks. I think the fact that the instances have different Ubuntu patch versions also confirms it

Comment: WSL1 is significantly smaller than WSL2 by the very nature of it